# Driving from Kampala to Lusaka in my own car

Tags: transportation

I am planning such a trip really soon. How long does it take? I am thinking going through Mutukula and onwards south to TZ/Zm border. ANyone with ideas about security, poor roads, hotels, towns to stay?

Comment: You are asking way too many things for a single question. There's no way anyone can possibly answer about driving, security, road quality, hotels, and which towns to stay in, without writing an entire travel guide. Please focus your post to one question. Make multiple posts if you wish.

Comment: I voted to re-open this question as this is not nearly as broad a question as it might sound. There is really only one option if you self-drive: Kampala - Bukoba - Mpanda - Tunduma - Lusaka. Stop in Kigoma for the only real city on the whole journey. Do not cross at Mbala (Zambia). Security is decent, though can be a bit dicey in eastern Tanzania. Decent enough hotels are available in the few towns along the way. Only drive during the day. Expect to take 6-8 days.

Comment: There may be only one route, but an answer covering hotels, security, roads, places to stay is asking for a condensed form of the Lonely Planet guide.

Comment: There's only one route, and pretty much the only towns that have decent enough hotels are exactly the towns you'd need to stay at if you don't want to travel by night or camp. The Kampala - Lusaka trip, for its 2500km, has very little diversity to offer as far as traveling from A to B is concerned.